# Why are Windows computers open to network file access by default?

Tags: network, windows

I'm on a work network, and I had some files I wanted to give to a colleague. I set up a shared folder and directed him to my computer name to open the shared folder. Then I remembered from a long time ago seeing C$, and tried I entering this:

```
\\COMPUTER-NAME\C$
```

Now, he got access to my computer. He could do everything on my file system, including adding files to the `startup` folder.

Why is this open for everybody by default? Why isn't this a feature one can enable on demand? It seems a good feature for the IT department, but after doing some research I found that the permission was in `LOCAL-COMPUTER-NAME\Administrators` (not in a separate group for the IT department). Does Microsoft just suppose most people doesn't know about this and leave it open by default? Or is it probably our IT department who set this up by mistake?

Comment: But this should be only available for windows xp, doesn't it? Also, this: http://superuser.com/questions/59708/shared-folders-and-c

Comment: I'm on Windows 7

Comment: But where are you trying this connection from?

Comment: I'm on the work Wifi logged on my own account (one of many other Domain accounts).

Comment: Yes but, how the scenario looks like? From where are you trying to access the C$ folder? Which are the privileges of each users?

Comment: All users on the domain can access everyone elses C$. I'm just a regular employee in the company. I don't have anything to do with the IT department. So I don't know much about exactly HOW AD works and how it's set up at our company.

Comment: @FriendofKim Then that means that all your users are, by some means or another, Administrators on all of your workstations. Your IT personnel need to be drug out to the street and shot. Actually, I wouldn't even waste time dragging them into the street - just shoot them right where they stand.

Comment: @Iszi Hehe, that sounds like this is pretty bad! Is it possible to set up AD so that a user only has got administrative rights on a computer based on it's name? Is it set up in AD that everyone's an administrator on every workstation?

Comment: @FriendofKim In your domain, it seems it is set up that everyone is an Administrator on every workstation. In fact, I'd almost worry that everyone just got dropped into Domain Administrators. You could download the Remote Server Administration Toolkit and run `dsa.msc` to explore the users and groups on your domain to find out. This is not at all how a domain is properly set up, though. You *can* individually assign users to be Administrators of their own computers and nobody else's. However, best practices don't even allow for that much unless it's absolutely needed for some users.

Comment: @Iszi So the best practice is then to add the user to the local administrators group manually (physically have the computer in front of you)? I'll try running the `dsa.msc`-file. If I have access to the whole AD I'll be a bit worried about the experience of the IT department...

Comment: @FriendofKim `dsa.msc` doesn't come pre-installed to Windows. You'll have to get the appropriate Remote Server Administration Tools from Microsoft. Any domain user can use that tool to browse AD normally. What else you can do (as far as adding/removing users and groups, changing group memberships, etc.) should be limited though.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your insight! Considering the permission granting access to `C$` is `Administrators (COMPUTER-NAME)` (or similar) everone has got to be an administrator. I'll look into this with the IT department. This can really be misused by our competitors.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C$ shares (and related $ADMIN,$IPC) are only available to members of the Administrators group.

These usually aren't a problem unless

1. The wrong people are made "Domain Administrators" in Active Directory
2. Two people are logged into their machine as "Administrator" with the same password.

According to the comments, you both log in as administrator, and because he was able to access your machine, the passwords must be the same... this is by design.

If you don't like this behaviour, then change your administrator password on both machines, and don't tell each other what that password is.  Additionally, you should create a separate account (non administrator) with a different username/password for all future work.

It is possible to disable the C$ share, but I wouldn't recommend it in a managed environment (with a decent network admin) since many administrative tools require this share to be present.  [You can disable this in GPO or the registry.](http://www.petri.co.il/disable_administrative_shares.htm)

Comment: Add to 1. "...and Domain Administrators are left in the local Administrators group on your systems."

Comment: Thank you for a good answer! I just have to clear some things up. I'm a hobby programmer and know quite a lot about computers in general. But I have very little experience with Windows domains because it's all just a hobby.

Comment: This is all happening on my work laptop which we are allowed to use for personal use outside of work hours. I'm going to try to understand what is happening here. We all have domain accounts we use to log in (DOMAIN\username). We all have administrator permissions on our own computers. This means that if I log into a collegues computer with MY username and password, it works, and I get administrator access to the computer.

Comment: Is it so that there are groups set up on each computer that has got a set of permissions, and Users and Administrators are shipped with Windows by default. Then each user can be added to the groups? All are added to Users and some to Administrators?

Comment: I found an administrator account on the computer, and when asking the IT department what it was for, they said it was to have access to my computer if I forgot my password. (They know the password, and it's probably the same on all computers.)

Comment: Now comes the domain. Is it so that AD is telling the computers that I log onto that my account is a regular User on the domain, but an Administrator on each local computer? The reason why I believe this is what's happening is that everyone logging onto a new computer gets administrative rights. And this is really set in AD?

Comment: Looking at the permissions of C: there was a tab to test permissions on any user in the domain. I found that everyone lost their permissions when removing the `Administrators (COMPUTER-NAME\username)`-line. Note that it's `COMPUTER-NAME` and not `DOMAIN-NAME`.

Comment: So by knowing a lot about computers and nothing about corporate user account management in Windows, my best guess would be that AD says that everyone's a local administrator on every computer connected to the domain? And then my best guess is that a "Domain Administrator" is an account that can change AD entries?

Comment: IIRC AD does not give domain users local admin rights by default. A domain admin has to set that right in AD. Admins will do this in most AD environments though.

Comment: So this basically means that in most corporate settings everyone can access the C$ because everyone are local administrators on every workstation?

Answer (score -2):

Not all of them are, they're disabled by default (although they still exist) from Vista onwards.

If you have the `$ADMIN`,`$IPC`, `$C` etc. shares open on your machine, and it's XP - then it's a default setting from Microsoft.  If you have them enabled for Win 7, Vista etc. then check whether they're actually accessible without credentials.

As to why, I think it was basically poor foresight, and laziness mixed together to create a really significant security bug, thankfully now mostly defunct.

Comment: So you're saying it's not enabled by default on Windows 7? I'm a local administrator, only on my own computer.

Comment: This is inaccurate. The given shares are enabled by default on all systems, at least up to Windows 7, when they are added to a domain.

Comment: Ah well, in that case I turn out to have been misinformed.

Comment: @Iszi I tried doing this on my home computer, and it asked for credentials. However, I've been setting up the permissions manually and carefully because I have a web server running on the network, so I don't know if this means that "C$-sharing" is disabled by default on Windows 7. Do you say that it is disabled on Windows 7 in a regular workgroup, but enabled on a domain by default?

Comment: @FriendofKim That's what I'm saying - a normal, fresh-out-of-the-box install of Windows will not have the administrative shares enabled. However, they are automatically turned on (unless there is a policy *against* it) once the system is joined to a domain.

Comment: @Iszi Okay. So it's simply because Microsoft believes IT departments to be smart enough to disable it for regular users! Thank you for your comments. It seems I'll have to bring this up with the IT department...

Comment: @FriendofKim IT departments don't need to "disable it for regular users" - it's already done. The administrative shares are only accessible to users who are in the Administrators group on the system. "Regular users" should *never* be in that group, let alone in that group on any computer other than the one on their own desk, so long as it can be practically avoided.

Comment: I just got my computer reset from an image they use for every computer on the company. I entered my username and password, and got administrative rights for my own computer. Everyone who logs onto any computer gets administrative rights on that computer. Is this set up in AD? So everyone are system administrators, but not domain administrators?